# How to set global variable under several conditions in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, edit, param

I am trying to transform a xml document which looks like this:

```
<CData>
    <Description>whatever</Description>
    <Property>
        <SetValue>123</SetValue>
        <Description>whatever</Description>
        <DefaultValue>321</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
      <Property>
        <SetValue>999</SetValue>
        <Description>whatever</Description>
        <DefaultValue>721</DefaultValue>
    </Property>
</CData>
```

Every CData tag is a table and property tags are representing a table row. Now I need a check for each CDate tag if the single Property tags have a Default and a SetValue and if they are different. The reason behind this is that I only want tables where the DefaultValue and the SetValue are different. Here is the check which is working fine:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CData">
  <xsl:for-each select="Property">
    <xsl:if test="SetValue">
      <xsl:if test="SetValue/text()!=''">
        <xsl:if test="DefaultValue">
          <xsl:if test="SetValue!=DefaultValue">
          //SET a Value
          </xsl:if
        </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not(DefaultValue)">
      //SET a VALUE
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In this check I need a Variable which will be set if the conditions are true and after this for-each loop I want to check the variable  with an if-tag and if it was set I want to print a table. The only problem I have now is that I don't know how to set a variable in the loop which I can use like a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how XSLT works - all variables are lexically scoped and you can't change the value of a variable once it has been created.

You need to think about the problem a bit differently.  Instead of the "procedural" view of a loop that goes through and tests conditions one by one and sets flags, you need to think more declaratively - use predicates to select the nodes that you are interested in:

```
<!-- this variable will contain only the Property elements that have a SetValue
     and a DefaultValue that are different -->
<xsl:variable name="interestingProperties"
     select="CData/Property[SetValue != DefaultValue]" />
```

and then take actions depending on whether or not any nodes were selected:

```
<xsl:if test="$interestingProperties">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="$interestingProperties">
      <tr>...</tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:if>
```

If you want to allow for Property elements that *don't* have a `DefaultValue` then you could change the predicates a bit:

```
<!-- this variable will contain only the Property elements that have a SetValue
     and do not also have a DefaultValue which matches it -->
<xsl:variable name="interestingProperties"
     select="CData/Property[SetValue][not(SetValue = DefaultValue)]" />
```

Here I'm using `not(X = Y)` instead of `X != Y` because the semantics are slightly different when you're dealing with node sets that might have zero or more than one member.  Essentially `SetValue != DefaultValue` says "there is some pair of one `SetValue` and one `DefaultValue` element such that their values are different" (which in particular means there must be at least one of each for the test to succeed), whereas `not(SetValue = DefaultValue)` means "it is not the case that there is a pair of `SetValue` and `DefaultValue` that match" (which can succeed if either the `SetValue` or the `DefaultValue` is missing, so we also need a separate `[SetValue]` to ensure that that is present).

Comment: '<xsl:variable name="interestingProperties"    select="Property[SetValue][DefaultValue][SetValue != DefaultValue]" />' works, but sometimes i have the case that i just have a SetValue tag in the Property tag and no DefaultValue tag. In this case the tables should be printed as well since a SetValue is differtent to the DefaultValue since it doesn't exist..

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="interestingProperties"
        select="Property[SetValue][DefaultValue or not(DefaultValue)][SetValue != DefaultValue or not(DefaultValue) ]" />` that works!

Comment: @user2435480 `[DefaultValue or not(DefaultValue)]` is redundant as that will always be true.  I've edited my answer with another more succinct suggestion.